# Creating paired array based on file name prefix match in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, prefix

I'm trying to create a for loop / while loop in bash which uses two different files (with same prefix). For example:

/home/samples - Contains files A-anything.fq B-anything.fq etc

/home/annotation - Contains files A-anything2.tab B-anything2.tab etc

I call their names in two separate arrays:

```sh
filepathsfq=( /home/samples/*fq )

filenamesfq=( "${filepathsfq[@]##*/}" ) #create an array so no
meta-characters in file name mess with anything

filepathstab=( /home/anottation/*tab )

filenamestab=("${filepathstab[@]##*/}")
```

I'm trying to create a double column array, such as `filenamesfq` and `filenamestab` are paired based on MATCH of the first 10 characters of strings (which is enough for full file pairing in my case, because the 10 first characters are file identifiers).

For example:

```
A12345689-anything.fq A12345689-anything2.tab
 
B12345689-anything.fq B12345689-anything2.tab
```

I tried with

```sh
declare -a a0=("${filepathsfq[@]##*/}")

declare -a a1=("${filepathstab[@]##*/}")
```

which does work, but I can't call the array on one for loop as one variable

I want this "paired array" because I'm trying to run a for loop which in need can only accept one variable. So this variable must contain all paired names.

I don't even know how to start pairing the names based on 10 first characters. I've been doing it by exporting the values to a CSV file and then using a formula to match the first 10 characters in excel, which is not great.

I also used:

```sh
paste -d, <(printf '%s\n' "${filepathsfq[@]##*/}") <(printf '%s\n' "${filepathstab[@]##*/}") >> samples.csv
```

To create a CSV file, manually verify if everything is paired correctly and then:

```sh
while IFS="," read fq tab
do
    echo $fq, $tab
done < samples.csv
```

The code above works for the intended purpose but need external validation for the name-matching. I can't figure how to match the file names and turn this into an array and use it in a for loop or a while loop

Comment: There are some border cases that you don't explain well enough: 1) What happens when there's a `C.fq` but no `C.tab`? 2) Why just the first 10 characters instead of the whole prefix? You'll potentially get `AC.fq` paired with `A.tab` and `A.fq` paired with `AC.tab`; do you need random pairings?

Comment: @GabrielG: It's not enough to say _I tried with_; you need to show what you actually tried, so that we can see where you are stuck. I also don't know what it means that _a variable turned into an array_. You usually don't change the type of a variable back and forth between array and scalar, but decide from the onlset, whether a variable is supposed to be an array or a scalar.

Comment: @Fravadona, In my specific case 10 characters is enough to guarantee that no single file will be the same! For the case of no "pair", I would create an if condition to export the failed files to a txt for example. I've also added some things that I've tried without success.

Comment: I do not understand, what is the end goal? `Which will output the paired values in the CSV file ` Great! so it works. So why are you writing here? What is your question? `but need external validation for the pairing` What do  you mean? `I don't even know how to start pairing the names` Exactly the same as you do with `paste` but `cut -c-10` the names to 10 characters. Also, if the filenames are the same in both dirs, why don't you just use one directory?

Comment: @KamilCuk I understand that maybe my question isn't clear enough on why I would need it. The thing is, if I need an external method to validate the pairing, it introduces manual work which I think could be automated so less human error comes into play! I'm a little new to more complex bash coding and I struggle with regex expressions, that is why I created a program to output the paired files to a CSV file, which works but is a workaround. I hope my edit makes the question clearer

Comment: restricting to the first 10 chars only makes sense when you want to match for example `A000000000XXX.fq` with `A000000000ZZZ.tab`; is that the case?

Comment: @Fravadona, that is exactly the case! The second file is further processed so the name changes a little, but the prefix is always the same (10 characters). I was working with your answer because I think it was on the right track!

Comment: @GabrielG. Updated my answer, it should be clear enough on how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the two directories:

```
/home/samples
|-- A12345689-anything.fq
|-- B12345689-anything.fq
|-- C12345689-anything0.fq
|-- C12345689-anything1.fq
`-- D12345689-anything.fq

/home/annotation
|-- A12345689-anything2.tab
|-- B12345689-anything2.tab
|-- C12345689-anything2.tab
`-- E12345689-anything2.tab
```

The following bash code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

fq_dirpath=/home/samples
tab_dirpath=/home/annotation

for fq_filepath in "$fq_dirpath"/*.fq
do
    prefix=${fq_filepath##*/}
    prefix=${prefix:0:10}

    fq_filepaths=( "$fq_dirpath"/"$prefix"*.fq )
    tab_filepaths=( "$tab_dirpath"/"$prefix"*.tab )

    # sanity checks
    [ ${#fq_filepaths[@]} -eq 1 ] || continue
    [ ${#tab_filepaths[@]} -eq 1 ] || continue

    fq_filename=${fq_filepaths##*/}
    tab_filename=${tab_filepaths##*/}

    # process the pair
    printf '%s %s\n' "$fq_filename" "$tab_filename"
done

shopt -u nullglob
```

outputs:

```
A12345689-anything.fq A12345689-anything2.tab
B12345689-anything.fq B12345689-anything2.tab
```